# Gallery swipe adjustment

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to lessen the amount of distance to be swiped in order to change my gallery's picture to the next. Right now this distance is at the standard rate and it's about half of the width of the gallery, but I need it to be about 1/3 or 1/4 of the total gallery width.

Thanks.

UPD: right now my custom gallery onFling returns false in order to list per page:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: do you want to show the next image on a fling action ?

Comment: I'm already sliding it image per flinge. It's achieved by return false; What I need is to make the fling distance less then it's now. the default fling action takes about half of the gallery distance in order to trigger the change.

Comment: Any luck with the problem solution?